# SQL - Cruzando tabelas dentro de tabelas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Não sei se o título é apropriado, mas vamos lá.

Eu tenho na Tabela A (tabela de processos consultados) dois campos chaves (processo_novo e processo_antigo) e tenho na Tabela B minha variável de interesse (assunto_processo_novo). Na Tabela C, tenho a conversão do processo antigo para o novo. Exemplificando:

```
Table A
pcs_novo   pcs_antigo   outras_A 
A          NULL         X
B          NULL         X
NULL       AA           X
NULL       BB           X
C          NULL         X
A          NULL         X
NULL       AA           X

Table B
pcs_novo   assunto  
A          1           
B          2       
C          3
D          4
E          5
F          6

Table C
pcs_antigo  pcs_novo
AA          D
BB          E
CC          F
```

Naturalmente, eu quero:

```
Final Table
    pcs_novo  pcs_antigo   assunto   outras_A
    A         NULL         1         X
    B         NULL         2         X
    D         AA           4         X
    E         BB           5         X
    C         NULL         3         X
```

Como eu consigo isso?

Notas:
Na Tabela A os campos de processos se repetem.
Na Tabela B e C os campos são únicos.

Comment: Usando junções. `LEFT JOINS` parecem as mais adequadas

Comment: Como eu faria isso?

Comment: a estrutura não me parece estar correta, teria algum modelo ER ?

Comment: @YuriCamaraBatista: o gerenciador de banco de dados é MySQL ou SQL Server? Os dois estão definidos como _tag_.

Comment: SQL Server, vou corrigir, obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comecemos ligando as tabelas `A` e `C`, assim teremos com certeza um `pcs_novo` válido:

```
SELECT
    coalesce(A.pcs_novo, C.pcs_novo) as pcs_novo,
    A.pcs_antigo,
    A.outros_a
FROM A 
    LEFT JOIN C ON (A.pcs_antigo = C.pcs_antigo)
```

O `coalesce` vai me garantir que, caso eu não consiga um valor não nulo de `A.pcs_novo`, ele vai pegar de `C.pcs_novo`.

O `LEFT JOIN` vai garantir que toda junção possível de `A` com `C` irá ser feita, e todas as linhas de `A` serão exibidas, mesmo aquelas que não possuam correspondência em `C`

Podemos pegar esse resultado e juntar com a tabela `B` para pegar o assunto:

```
SELECT
    coalesce(A.pcs_novo, C.pcs_novo) as pcs_novo,
    A.pcs_antigo,
    B.assunto,
    A.outros_a
FROM A 
    LEFT JOIN C ON (A.pcs_antigo = C.pcs_antigo)
    LEFT JOIN B ON (coalesce(A.pcs_novo, C.pcs_novo) = B.pcs_novo)
```

Como as linhas em `A` podem ter `pcs_novo` ou `pcs_antigo` repetidos, para pegar apenas os valores únicos para os processos, podemos usar o `distinct` para não pegar as repetições:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    coalesce(A.pcs_novo, C.pcs_novo) as pcs_novo,
    A.pcs_antigo,
    B.assunto,
    A.outros_a
FROM A 
    LEFT JOIN C ON (A.pcs_antigo = C.pcs_antigo)
    LEFT JOIN B ON (coalesce(A.pcs_novo, C.pcs_novo) = B.pcs_novo)
```

Comment: vou tentar e já te dou um feedback!

Comment: Vai ter algumas repetições porque no momento da escrita da minha resposta eu não tinha visto que poderia haver repetição na tabela `A`. Vou colocar o `distinct` para garantir que nenhuma repetição indesejada apareça

Comment: sem problemas, faltou mesmo eu deixar claro isso na pergunta.

Comment: Estou quase lá Jefferson. Tem uma questão que não estou conseguindo resolver por conta do coalesce. Meu campo pcs_novo é na verdade dois campos (ano_pcs_novo e nro_pcs_novo). A princípio não coloquei isso no tópico pois pensei que qualquer resposta poderia ser adaptada com um simples "and" nas condições (ex: LEFT JOIN C on (A.ano_novo = B.ano_novo and A.pcs_novo = B.pcs_novo). Mas no coalesce não consegui ainda adaptar. Como eu poderia adaptar no caso?

Comment: Método não performático: concatenando as informações como strings. Método mais performático: `coalesce` da `ano_novo` igual ao C.ano_novo AND `coalesce` da `nro_pcs_novo` igual ao C.nro_novo. A junção de `A` com `C` não deve ter segredo

Comment: Quando eu estiver no computador novamente eu atualizo para com os dados da pergunta atualizada

Comment: Deu certo! Muitíssimo obrigado!